# How to return a substring after it occurs after another string?

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a long string of which I am attempting to get return a string after it occurs after
another string.  For example, I look for the string 'zombiesattack' in the string first, I
then look for the first place that the string named 'title' occurs and want to print the save the text in between 'title' and '/title' to another variable named 'titleOfVideo'.  I am having some difficulty doing this.  Any advice?

## string stored in the variable named data

```
data= <updated>2012-10-10T19:20:55.000Z</updated>
<abc>zombiesattack</abc>
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video" />
<category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat" term="Sports" label="Sports" />
<title>NY Yankees: 6 Essential Pieces of Postseason Memorabilia</title>
```

I'd like to save 'NY Yankees: 6 Essential Pieces of Postseason Memorabilia' to the variable 'titleOfVideo'.

```
starting_point = data.find('zombiesattack')
new_string = data[starting_point:]
title_point = new_string.find('<title>')
print new_string[:title_point]

titleOfVideo = new_string[title_point:20]
```

When I try this and print titleOfVideo, I get a bunch of return lines.

Comment: Use python's built in [XML parser](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) rather than trying to do a bunch of manual string matching.

Comment: How would I implement this with XML parser? I'm reading the documentation but am having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a XML parser instead, such as ElementTree:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
# you need a valid xml string
data = '<root>' + data + '</root>'
etree = ElementTree.fromstring(data)
if etree.findtext('abd') == 'zombiesattack':
    titleOfVideo = etree.findtext('title')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example:

```
starting_point = data.find('zombiesattack')
new_string = data[starting_point:]
title_start = new_string.find('<title>')
title_end = new_string.find('</title>')
titleOfVideo = new_string[title_start + len('<title>'):title_end]
```